# How to define a tranform listener

Tags: ros, laser-geometry, transform-listener, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using this [code](http://answers.ros.org/question/3336/building-point-cloud-using-input-from-position) in order to relate the point cloud with the pose information.

Also, the code found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) looks like below:

```
laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;

void scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in)
{
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
  projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link",*scan_in,cloud,listener_);

  // Do something with cloud.
}
```

How should I define the "listener_" variable in order to use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12454/how-to-define-a-tranform-listener/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just as done in the example. Put it somewhere, the only important thing is that it is persistent, i.e. it doesn't go out of scope and is recreated all the time.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-26**:
Thanks a lot for the explanation. I got it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-26**:
Yes, it does everything by itself. It just needs to stay to collect some data instead of being recreated all the time.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-25**:
Did you mean "listener_" variable there something need not be defined ourselves but it's configured/(storing values) by itself?